# I want the theorem in beamer not italics

Tags: beamer, fonts, theorems

I want the theorem tag and the contents in theorem of beamer not italics.

Currently it shows like

[image]

I want "This is a theorem" not italics.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
  {%
    {\bfseries\upshape\inserttheoremname%
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition \fi}%
    \space\normalfont%
  }%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Theorem}
\begin{theorem}[hello]
This is a theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `\normalfont` outside of the group so it will also effect the body of the theorem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
  {%
    {\bfseries\upshape\inserttheoremname%
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition \fi}%
  }%
  \space\normalfont%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Theorem}
\begin{theorem}[hello]
This is a theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is an simple solution.

Comment: @Harry You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You only need

```latex
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[normal font]
```

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[normal font]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Theorem}
\begin{theorem}[hello]
This is a theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]