# how to make block content not in a new line in beamer

Tags: beamer, environments, block

I want the block content does not from a new line from block title, what should I do?
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\normalfont,series=\bf}
\begin{block}{block title}
This is block content
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know how to redefine the `theorem begin` template to remove the line break. Just use your definition from [I want the theorem in beamer not italics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/687514/36296)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
  {%
    {\bfseries\upshape\inserttheoremname%
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition \fi}%
  }%
  \space\normalfont%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Theorem}
\begin{theorem}[hello]
This is a theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, I have tried and found it can be transferred.